# Remove the slash (/) at the end of my routee

Tags: vue.js, routes, path, nuxt.js, slash

I would like to know some way to remove the slash at the end of the routes in Nuxtjs.

I have tried with the @nuxtjs redirect-module and setting the trailingSlash property to false, but when I do it, far from removing the slash, it puts many more at the end.

For example:
Original path: "myroute/"
Path I want: "myroute"
Path that appears when putting some of those changes: "myroute///////////////////"

Comment: Are you seeing trailingSlash though you go to route without trailingSlash? can you provide some more details on this "myroute///////////////////"?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're describing seems unusual and might be caused by a combination of configurations or other plugins affecting the routes. However, here's a way you can handle trailing slashes using a middleware:

add a `middleware/remove-trailing-slash.js` :

```
export default function({ route, redirect }) {
  if (route.path !== '/' && route.path.endsWith('/')) {
    let newPath = route.path.slice(0, -1);
    redirect(301, newPath);
  }
}
```

This checks if the path ends with a slash and redirects to the same path without it.

Then, all you have to do is to register it in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
export default {
  router: {
    middleware: ['remove-trailing-slash']
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!